# How to use gcloud Python API locally

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to access one of my buckets on GCP. I use the `storage.Client()` method to make a client, but it doesn't authenticate when I try to run it. I know I can set my environment to have my credentials but I'm not really understanding the docs on it. How do I do so?

Comment: can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to access my bucket using `storage.Client()` method.

First of all you must make sure you have installed the Cloud Storage library correctly.

For that you can use the following command on Cloud Shell `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`.

For this I have created a program in python which uploads a file stored locally to my bucket. You can see [my code here](https://github.com/chris32g/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Cloud%20Functions/uploadFileToBucket).

I'm running this program from Cloud Shell.